# Syslog-NG TLS configuration issue (peer did not return a certificate)

Tags: ssl, syslog-ng

Configuring a syslog-ng server to receive syslog messages from a cloud service over TLS.

The syslog-ng server is on an Ubuntu instance on Azure and the latest version (4.5).

This is a basic configuration to test the implementation. I have created a self signed certificate for the server for testing.

When the server is run and have the cloud service send logs over, this error message is on the syslog server console:

**SSL error while reading stream; tls_error='error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate', location='/etc/syslog-ng/tls.conf:4:1'**

config file:

```
@version:4.5
source demo_tls_source {
tcp(port(6514)
tls( key_file("/etc/syslog-ng/cert.d/syslog.key")
cert_file("/etc/syslog-ng/cert.d/syslog.crt")
ca_dir("/etc/syslog-ng/cert.d"))
); };
destination d_file { file("/var/log/fromnet"); };
log { source(demo_tls_source); destination(d_file); };
```

Unsure how to troubleshoot this issue, any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syslog-ng is configured for mutual authentication, so it expects a certificate from the client, but it seems that the cloud service doesn't send one. You can either:

- configure your cloud service to send a certificate that syslog-ng can verify, or
- configure syslog-ng to accept the connection without a certificate. For this option, see [Disabling mutual authentication](https://axoflow.com/docs/axosyslog-core/chapter-encrypted-transport-tls/tls-serverauth/procedure-configuring-tls-server/#example-disabling-mutual-authentication) (the link points to the documentation of Axosyslog, which is a cloud-ready syslog-ng distribution maintained by the original creator of syslog-ng)